# R create a loop for a list of data frames

Tags: r, function, loops

I currently have a list which is made up of around 80+ data frames, what I would like to do is to loop a chunk of code for each individual data frame within the list, without naming each one individually, or splitting them into individual data frames to work on.

Currently I split the list into each individual data frame using the below code:

```
dat5split <- setNames(split(dat5, dat5$CODE), paste0("df", unique(dat5$CODE)))

list2env(dat5split, globalenv())
```

I then work through each data frame individually:

```
    # call in SPC function and write to 'results10000'

    results10000<-SPC_XBAR(df10000,vol_n,seasonality)

    results10000 = results10000 %>%
      cbind(Spec = df10000$CODE) %>%
      subset(`table_n` == 1)

    results10000 <- results10000[order(results10000$tpd),]

    results10000$Date <- as.Date(cbind(Date = df10000$CENSUS_DATE))

# call in SPC function and write to 'results10001'

    results10001<-SPC_XBAR(df10001,vol_n,seasonality)

    results10001 = results10001 %>%
      cbind(Spec = df10001$CODE) %>%
      subset(`table_n` == 1)

    results10001 <- results10001[order(results10001$tpd),]

    results10001$Date <- as.Date(cbind(Date = df10001$CENSUS_DATE))
```

Currently I call in the function 'SPC_XBAR' to where vol_n and seasonality are set earlier in the code. The script then passes the values to the function which then assigns the results to 'results10000, results10001' etc etc. Upon which I do a small bit of data wrangling on each newly created data frame before feeding the results back into sql server at the end.

As you can see each one is being individually hard coded which is not efficient.

What I would like to do is to loop a chunk of code for each individual data frame within the list, without naming each one individually.

I believe a loop would solve this issue but I am a little inexperienced when it comes to the ability to create a loop around it. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `lapply` instead of a loop throughout the list? Check it [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply)...

EDIT: I try to elaborate a bit more... What happens if you do this:

```
myFunction <- function(x) {
    results<-SPC_XBAR(x,vol_n,seasonality)

    results = results %>%
      cbind(Spec = x$CODE) %>%
      subset(`table_n` == 1)

    results <- results[order(results$tpd),]

    results$Date <- as.Date(cbind(Date = x$CENSUS_DATE))

    results
}

lapply(dat5split, myFunction)
```

I would expect it to return a list of the resulting datasets

Comment: When I try to use `lapply` using the following code: results <- `lapply(dat5split, SPC_XBAR(vol_n, seasonality))` i get the following error `Error in attach(dat4) : 
  'attach' only works for lists, data frames and environments` I am assuming that I am entering the vol_n and seasonality into the correct position?

Comment: unfortunately a slightly different error code now appears `Error in seq.default(i, length(vol), seasonality) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument `  when I traceback to the function it appears to be falling over on this line of code `dt<-(assign(nam, vol[seq(i, length(vol), seasonality)]))`

Comment: Marco, Just to inform you that your answer is correct, the issue was caused by an erroneous data which the SPC_XBAR function did not like. Once I removed said data your function to loop through the list of data frames worked a treat. Thank you very much for this.